# Application that creates restore points in xp

Tags: windows-xp, system-restore

Is there any application for windows xp/windows 7 that could create system restore points on the go. 
Because the system restore in xp is not very fast in creating restore points. You still have to set many things before you can create one.
I want one with just one button and when you click it. A restore point is created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google leads us to the [Quick Restore Maker](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/create-a-system-restore-point-in-1-click-with-quick-restore-maker), which does pretty much what you describe.